# How can I measure the stability of a many body gravitational system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, celestial-mechanics, many-body

Suppose I have an N body planetary system interacting via gravity.  Suppose I know the  positions and momenta at t=0.  How do I know if this system is stable (indefinitely)?  By stable I mean the system is approximately periodic (if even over a very long scale and not quite returning to the initial configuration) and true under small perturbations (no unstable equilibria).

In some sense, how to calculate whether such an orbital system 'could actually persist' if it happened to initially be in sone configuration?

Comment: What research have you done about this problem?  eg "Predictability, Stability, and Chaos in N-Body Dynamical Systems" ed Archie E Roy (Springer).

Comment: You could look into the KAM-theorem, I think this covers what your looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/KAM_theory_in_celestial_mechanics#Properly_degenerate_KAM_theory

Comment: Even with the KAM theorem you can't check if a particular configuration is stable, or not. The KAM theorem only tells you that there are such configurations, but it can't give you a guarantee that you can identify them using finite precision floating point numerics.